# Flattens (explodes) compound values into multiple rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Flatten can be used for following semi structure and structure data, or only semi structure.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten is for a VARIANT, OBJECT, or ARRAY.  Unpivot will work on structured data.

Comment: Thanks! 
I have one more question Mike.
If we want to delete data in fail safe whether user or snowflake support can delete it before 7 days period expires.

Comment: There is no option to delete data from failsafe.  To avoid failsafe, use transient tables.